# Unable to Submit to iTunes Store with Xcode 9 GM

Tags: xcode, xcode9

Every time I upload my app, I get these messages but I have all the assets in the AppIcon assets and removed the CFBundleIconFiles from my info.plist

I am using CocoaPods for GooglePlayGames, Google Ads and Google Signin

[image: failure image]

[image: AppIcon Assets]

Comment: Show your AppIcon asset from Xcode showing that you actually have all of the icons shown here as missing.

Comment: assets are shown

Comment: @rmaddy any thing else I can do to resolve my issue?

Comment: does XCode throw any warnings related to assets?

Comment: no warnings. I found this article that forces Xcode to work but it's an ugly hack. Maybe it's a bug in Xcode 9 GM

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the sizes you are putting in the asset spots are off.  I use this site for icons its great. https://applypixels.com